# Are classes namespaces in C++?

Tags: c++, class, enums, namespaces

Are classes namespaces in C++? I am asking this because the following code is valid. Could someone explain why?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

class MainClass{
public:
  enum Bool{False, True};

  MainClass(){
    std::cout << "MainClass constructor" << True << std::endl;
  }
  ~MainClass(){
    std::cout << "MainClass destructor" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(){
  MainClass::Bool myvar = MainClass::False << std::endl; //Why is this line valid?
  std::cout << myvar;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: classes and namespaces are both _scopes_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classes are not namespaces. However the `Bool` enum is defined in `MainClass`'s scope, so the scope resolution operator `::` applies.

Comment: so I cant say ```using namespace MainClass;``` in order to refrain from having to type it. every time?

Comment: No, you cannot. `using` requires a namespace name.

Comment: You can use `using Bool = ::MainClass::Bool;` (I think... I've not tried it, because haven't need to do it.)

Answer (score 3):

In C++ there is a `namespace` and there is also a `class`, a namespace is not a class. Your code is valid because you can nest enums, structs, classes, etc, within classes.

Answer (score 3):

> Are classes namespaces in C++?

No classes are not namespaces.

But classes have a scope, just like namespaces have a scope.